# How do I search an array for a string

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Iv'e been trying to search an array for a certain string but I do not know the process of doing it could someone please write a code that will help me understand thanks.

This here is just a tiny piece of code, I don't think im close at all to the search function to work

```
case '3': cout << "you wish to search for a book\n please type the book Title you are looking for." << endl;

        getline(cin, srch);
        for (i = 0;Book[i].GetBookTitle() ; i++)
        {
         ( Book[i].GetBookTitle()== srch)

        }

        break;
```

Comment: there just used to repeat a process as many times as you set the increment. The book[i] that is in there is totally wrong. So may I please have the answer to my question. maybe just make a search function template for strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop needs a limit:

```
bool found = false;
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BOOKS_IN_ARRAY ; i++)
{
  if ( Book[i].GetBookTitle()== srch)
  {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

I also terminated the loop, via `break`, if the book is found.
A flag variable, `found`, is set to `true` if the book was found.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for code that looks like this:

```
string srch;
cout << "you wish to search for a book\n please type the book Title you are looking for." << endl;
getline(cin, srch);
for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++) {
    if (Book[i].GetBookTitle() == srch) {
        cout << "Book found!" << endl;
    }
}
```

The value of "Max" is the number of books in your database.